# How to configure crontab to run ec2-automate-backup.sh script

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, cron

Hi guys am trying to automate the backup of snapshots for my ec2 volumes on Amazon. I am following the ec2-automate-backup script by Collin Johnson
If run the command on command line it is creating the snapshot (working):

```
ubuntu@linuxserver:/usr/local/ec2/scripts$ sudo ./ec2-automate-backup.sh -s tag -t "Backup,Values=true" -c ./cron-primer.sh -r "eu-west-1"
```

For testing purposes if i create a crontab its not working

```
0 10  * * *  ubuntu /usr/local/ec2/scripts/ec2-automate-backup.sh -s tag -t "Backup,Values=true" -c /usr/local/ec2/scripts/cron-primer.sh -r "eu-west-1"
```

Where is my problem here am running the script on ubuntu 14.04 - Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

In `crontab` file, to execute a shell script you can use one of the following approach:

**1. Call the shell script direcly**, i.e.

```
0 10 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

where the script.sh should be made executable.

**2. Execute the script by `sh` utility**, i.e.

```
0 10 * * * sh /path/to/script.sh
```

here the script.sh need not be made executable.

Now, if in your case, you need to go to a specific path and then execute script, then :

- Either provide the full path of the script in `crontab` file directly, or
- Enclose the execution commands in other shell file, and execute the enclosing file from `cron`.

Comment: 0 10 * * * ubuntu cd /usr/local/ec2/scripts && ./ec2-automate-backup.sh -s tag -t "Backup,Values=true" -c ./cron-primer.sh -r "eu-west-1"   : I provided the path as you said, but still its not working.

Comment: You're putting extra "." in front of the script path. It should be plain path,.i.e.`/path/to/script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilites:

1. You need root access to run the script. You can solve this by modifying root's crontab:

   `sudo crontab -e`

See [How to run a cron job using the sudo command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173924/how-to-run-a-cron-job-using-the-sudo-command)

2. You need to be in the same directory as the script to execute it

   `0 10 * * * ubuntu cd /usr/local/ec2/scripts && ./ec2-automate-backup.sh -s tag -t "Backup,Values=true" -c ./cron-primer.sh -r "eu-west-1"`

See [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion to no avail. I dont know what is it that am doing wrong. all the 2 scripts i have set to executable mode sudo chmod +x ec2-automate-backup.sh cron-primer.sh